# How can I rename a NULL label for 2 checkboxes in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that takes 2 DATETIME parameters.  The parameters can be NULL whereby I set the parameters to specific values in the stored procedure but if they are populated from the SSRS report then I use those values. In SSRS I have a problem where I am needing to change the NULL label to something else but I can't find a way to do that.  In the REPORT PARAMETER PROPERTIES I set each parameter to a DATE/TIME value with the ALLOW NULL VALUE checkbox checked and visible so that the user can uncheck the NULL checkbox and set the actual date parameters using the calendar button.

Is there a way to change the NULL label for the checkbox?  Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Here is the PIC of the PREVIEW SCREEN for the report in SSRS:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there's a way to change the `NULL` label, unless you were to write some custom code which would be A LOT of work.  The best alternative that I can think of, is to remove the property for `ALLOW NULL VALUES` and simply set the default value to something you prefer.  For example, you can set the `Statement End Date` to `=Now()` which will give you the current date.  For `Statement Start Date`, potentially you could write a query to grab the first date from your database.

[Here's a useful link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/879b0015-b053-40de-b97d-620fc283e542/how-to-change-null-label-of-the-checkbox-in-the-parameter-area?forum=sqlreportingservices) that could help you out, as well.

Answer (score 2):

In report parameters properties, click on Allow blank values("") and Allow null values, on default values click on specify values and type in (Null).

Within your query for your dataset , specifically the where criteria enter the following:

WHERE      startdatevalue = @Paramstartdate OR @Paramstartdate IS NULL
and
enddatevalue = @Paramenddate OR @Paramenddate IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

I read the xml of the rdl-file, and in my version of SSRS, the word "NULL" for the checkbox does not appear there, and hence  cannot be readily changed.

Therefore:
One *can* add an explanation text box to the header of the report, e.g. :

```
NOTE: For parameters above, NULL allows them to take on "ANY" value in the search.
```

Obviously, this is just a work-around and not a true-solution but it may add to user-friendliness.

Many users don't know what 'NULL' means, and it tends to have a negative connotation.