# Is there a way to change the NULL text of a NULLABLE report parameter

Tags: reporting-services, null

Iam trying to change this Null word next to a nullable parameters in ssrs to user friendly words but couldn't find easy way to do it in SSRS, Can anyone help with that , please ?

Thanks in advance

[this is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXv3l.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rename a NULL label for 2 checkboxes in SSRS report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788665/how-can-i-rename-a-null-label-for-2-checkboxes-in-ssrs-report)

Comment: @GonenI Thanks for your answer, I think ny client needs  to change the 'null' word to another thing to be user friendly to the report users :).

Comment: @Noora As far as I could see that's exactly what the asker of the question I linked wanted. Basically the answer he got was no, there is no way.